# Potential energy of a single point-mass in an upright object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

Does a point-mass on one end of an object sitting upright have gravitational potential energy?

An example would be a balanced pencil.  Does a point-mass on the top end of the pencil have gravitational potential energy?

Comment: A point mass does not *have* potential energy. The potential energy is assigned to the system of interacting objects. For gravitational potential energy to be considered you must have at least 2 masses in the system.

Comment: @BillN Oh right.  I actually already understood this yesterday but straight-up forgot it the next day.  Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nice question. Elementary work done by force is $$ dW = F \,dx  $$
Substituting for a gravitational force and integrating both sides gives :
$$ W = \int G \frac {Mm}{x^2} dx $$
Now changing it into definite integral (work needed to move mass by gravitational field from $R$ to $r$ distance) and noticing that $W = E_{pot}$, gives :
$$ E_{pot} = \int_R^r G \frac {Mm}{x^2} dx$$
which is :
$$ E_{pot} = GMm \left(\frac 1R - \frac1r\right) $$
where $r$ is your point mass current distance from gravitational body center of mass (Earth COM this time) and $R$ is zero gravitational energy distance, i.e. distance from a gravitational body COM where you consider $E_{pot} = 0$.

So the final answer it depends how you choose zero energy point $R$, and it can be arbitrary point. In case :

- $R=r \,\,\,\,\,\,\to E_{pot} = 0\,\,\,\,\,$ (As in $E_{pot}=mgh$, when $h=0$)
- $R=\infty \,\,\,\to E_{pot} = -G\,M\,m\,r^{-1}$
- $R=0 \,\,\,\,\,\to E_{pot} = \infty \,\,\,\,\,\, \text{with any}\,\,r$ (Almost never used because of singularity)

So choose your zero point wisely.

**EDIT**

As @looksquirrel101 correctly pointed out, singularity at point $R=0$ can be removed by other means.

Comment: Your formula is valid for points outside the surface of the Earth. If you move to inside the Earth, then there is a different result and $R=0$ is not singular. If you assume that the density if the earth is only a function of $r$ and is spherical, then one derivation uses the interesting result that there is no gravitational force on a point mass inside a spherical shell.

Comment: _Your formula is valid for points outside the surface of the Earth_ Nope, just for $r < R \,\, \to E_{pot} < 0$, i.e. gravitational potential energy will shift sign and it's normal, because potential energy sign depends on **where** you choose zero point of potential energy. I think I pretty much explained that. Btw, negative potential is pretty standard definition, besides you will get same situation with $E=mgh$ definition if zero energy point you choose at **surface** and your body lies below it, i.e. $h < 0$.

Comment: In my formula when $R \to 0$ : $$\left(\frac 1R - \frac1r\right) \to \left(\infty - \frac1r\right)$$ And $$ \infty - x = \infty \,\,\text{for any}\,x\,\, \text{except}\,\, \infty $$, so $R=0$ **IS** singularity in my formula and I'm not talking about other formulas, just this one.

Comment: @Angius Vasiliauskus - If you are falling through a hole through the center of a uniform density sphere of total radius $R$ and total mass $M$, when you are at a distance $r$ from the center it is only the mass of the sphere of radius $r$ that places a force on you, not the total mass of the sphere of radius $R$.  The net force from the shell outside of your position places no net force upon you.  The force on you is towards the center of the sphere and is equal to $F=G m M r / R^3$. Hence, inside the sphere the potential energy is just $E_p = G m M r^2 / 2 R^3$. No singularity at $r=0$.

Comment: Yes, it can be re-calculated by other means to remove that singularity as you did it, that's why I said that it is only in **MY** formula a singularity. Have you noticed what I've wrote or you just skipped it ?

Comment: I am simply providing the solution to the physical problem, which of course has no singularity.  As I pointed out, your formula is valid for points outside of the surface of the Earth, which means it is not valid for $R=0$.

Comment: I know that it is not valid for $R=0$, that's why i called it singularity at that point.

Comment: Btw, in my formula $R$ is not a gravitational body $M$ radius, but it's a **distance** at which $E_{pot} = 0$ and [can be chosen arbitrary](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Mechanics/gravpe.html), even be set to infinity. So our semantic meaning for $R$ is different.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, gravitational potential energy ( assuming it's only affected by the gravitational field of the earth) of a point mass exists at any place in the Universe. As on the top of a pencil.

It is given by the formula :

$U(r)$ = $\frac{- GMm}{r}$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The potential energy is:

$$U=-mgL $$

With:

$$mg=\dfrac{mMG}{\left( R+L\right)^2}\approx\dfrac{mMG}{R^{2}}$$

Thus $g=\frac{MG}{R^2}$

And

$$U=-mMG\left( \dfrac{L}{R^{2}}\right) $$